# How to check if a string from file exists in any line of another file and copy that line to new file

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am new to Bash commands. How do I write this script to get the output shown below? **NOTE:** I have two files.

`file.txt`:

```
i am going home
i am eating
He is working
```

`patterns.txt`:

```
going
eating
```

I would like to have the following in `outputfile.txt`:

```
i am going home
i am eating
```

Comment: A simple `grep(1)` will give you what you want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `grep`:

```
grep -Ff patterns.txt file.txt > outputfile.txt
```

`-f` tells it to read patterns from a file, and `-F` to treat the as fixed strings rather than regular expressions.
If you want to match whole *words* (as opposed to strings), then add `-w` to the grep options.

Comment: nitpick: I'd also add a `-w` here to only match full words. For instance, not match "bleating" or "outgoing", etc.

Comment: @filbranden I did consider that - however the question title does say *string* rather than *word* (perhaps it's just malicious compliance on my part though)

Comment: I agree that there's quite a bit of "guessing" what the intent really was there... Oh well, your answer is great.

Comment: @filbranden thanks for your comments - I've edited in a note about that option, hopefully that covers both possibilities

Comment: @steeldriver Is there a way to have the opposite: all lines in `patterns.txt` that are NOT FOUND in `file.txt`? NB: if I add the `-v` option, I get something different: all lines in `file.txt` that does not match any of those in `patterns.txt`